# How to space text like using tab on website?

Tags: html, css

I just got another assignment for web design. And I was curios how to space text like this. [image: Text spacing]

The issue here is not the heading nor the text on the left. I have problem with the time on the right. We are forbidden to edit html which looks like this:

```
<div class="oteviracka">
<h2>Otevírací doba</h2>
<p><strong>Po &ndash; Pá:</strong> 11:00 &ndash; 23:00</p>
<p><strong>So:</strong> 11:00 &ndash; 24:00</p>
<p><strong>So:</strong> 11:00 &ndash; 22:00</p>
</div>
```

I tried almost everything but the code was always "dirty" and I doubt it is done by the way I did it. (First-child spacing and so).

So my question is **How to space text like using tab with CSS?**

Comment: Honestly, that looks like a table. Use one :)

Comment: Please post the code you tried. This will help us figure out your approach.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks "We are forbidden to edit html."

Comment: Please tell your professor to add abbr[title] elements on abbreviations like Po, Pà and So ;)

Comment: Otherwise, +1 to Amit Bhargava: where's your current CSS code? What are you trying to align and how? Centering periods of time or left aligned or right-aligned? You can align to the right with current HTML code: `text-align: right;` your paragraphs and do the opposite (`text-align: left;`) with the `strong` elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the rule `display: inline-block` on the `strong` elements. This rule is combination of inline but with the ability to specify a size:

```
p strong { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px
    /* IE7 */
    *display: inline; 
    zoom: 1;
    /* IE7 */
}
```

[**​DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/y9ndq/1/)

Further reading:

- [CSS Display rule (on SitePoint)](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display)